# Airflow Dataproc operator to run shell scripts

Tags: python, shell, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

Is there any direct way to run shell scripts into dataproc cluster. currently i can run the shells through pysparkoperator (which calls aonther python file and then this python file calls shell script). I have searched many links but as of now not found any direct way .

It will be really helpful for me if anybody can tell me the easiest way.

Comment: I don't know a `direct` way, but in case you are not aware, you can 1)find the running Dataproc master node Name 2)`gcloud compute ssh` to that instance

Comment: Hi , yes using this option we can work on shell scripts manually but my objective is to schedule this script through airflow . Let me know if you can help me more. Thanks in advance

Comment: All with PythonOperator, You can use `googleapiclient.discovery.build('dataproc', 'v1', credentials=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())` to get the running dataproc, then `subprocess.Popen` with `gcloud compute ssh` by passing the correct instance name

Answer (score 1):

PIG job with `sh` operator [1]: `gcloud dataproc jobs submit pig ... -e 'sh ls'`

I am however curious what the end goal is? Why run shell scripts? If your intent is to perform one-time cluster setup then you should use initialization actions [2].

[1] https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cmds.html#sh

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/init-actions

Answer (score 0):

You can use airflow **BashOperator** and use the following command:

```
gcloud compute ssh user@server --zone your_cluster_zone \
  --command='Your Command'
```

**Example:**

```
    BashCommand= BashOperator(
    task_id='BashCommand',
    bash_command='gcloud compute ssh user@server --zone your_cluster_zone --command='Your Command',
    dag=dag)
```